# how to monitor user accessed files

Tags: .net, winapi

I'm developing a security application about file accessing. so need to monitor witch files are user accesse in there PC (file path & name with extension). file may located in HDD, CD, or portable devices  I know virus gird can do this. I cant figure out how to do this.

thanks in advance

I need to create a log like this:

```
user1 - [file deleted] [D:/abc.txt] 3:20 AM 
user1 - [file opened] [D:/New Folder/xyz.doc] 4:20 AM 
user1 - [file renamed] [D:/New Folder/video1.mpg] to [video2.mpg] 5:10 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anti-malware software does this using file system filter drivers. The documentation for which can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff548202.aspx

This is a large and tricky field, not for the feint of heart. To put you off even more, you'll get nowhere coding this with .net. You have to code this using unmanaged code.

Comment: thank you for the answer. may be I just need to simple thing than I explain in my question. I need to create a log like this:

user1 - [file deleted] [D:/abc.txt] 3:20 AM
user1 - [file opened] [D:/New Folder/xyz.doc] 4:20 AM

is there easy way to doing this. please show me.

Comment: I think I understood fine. *Is there an easy way to do this?* No there is not.